# Falha ao instalar MySql Server 5.x no Windows 10 (64bits)

Tags: mysql, windows-10

Boa noite,

estou tentando instalar o MySql Server 5.x (32 e 64bits) no Windows 10 (64bits), mas no meio da instalação o processo é abortado com a seguinte mensagem:

'...não há versão disponível do MySql Server...'

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O MySQL Installer para Windows fará os downloads dos arquivos de acordo com os itens que você selecionar nos passos iniciais da instalação. Provavelmente não está conseguindo conectar-se ã Internet.

Uma alternativa é baixar os arquivos para instalação manual em https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ . Selecione MySQL Community Server, Operating Syatem Windows e o arquivo Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive (aprox. 300MB). Depois descompacte e rode o mysqld.exe. Você poderá instalar como serviço do Windows com o parâmetro --install.